# android apk stopped working even on AVD all is good

Tags: java, android, apk

I have written some program, which takes streaming data from host. I used this example: https://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/ It works fine on my Android Virtual Device (2.3.3 API level 10) but when I created .apk and installed on Galaxy S4 and LG P710 and I get error `unfortunately, has stopped`.  Whats is wrong? How do I debug this?

Comment: Look at you Logcat output to check the exception and post it here to know what's going on.

Comment: I tried AVD Android 4.4.2 API level 19 and I get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. So how do I fix it to run on any android?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Check my answer below and mark it as the correct answer if it is for you.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/  this source I am using. So where do I add this your code?

Comment: why do I get -1 on my question? Who asks a qestion may look stupid for 5 minutes but he who doesn't ask will be stupid for the reste of his life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment you get the exception `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`: In new Android APIs, You should put any code that access network or internet inside different Thread.

Try this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Put your code here

            }
        }).start();
```

**Edit 1:**
You can use any background threading construct that comes with Android. Thread inside Service, Thread (as mentioned) or AsyncTask. Each has pros and crons. You should investigate  this. Small hint, if you play this inside this activity and access the activity user interface some how, Use AsycnTask.

Comment: Using AsyncTasks might be more useful on Android. Check here, how AsyncTasks work: http://open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=54

Answer (score 1):

To debug it on your device, you have to use ADB with your smartphone device. To do so, enable `USB Debugging` on the device, connect it to the computer and make sure (if on `Windows`) that `USB` drivers are installed. Finally launch `Eclipse` or `Android Studio` and launch your project in debug mode. You should see a console output, where the full stacktrace of your device is visible.

If you do not have the possibility to debug with your computer <-> smartphone, try to use [BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com/). Its free and including its library into your project it sends a full stack trace to you if errors do occur.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your device do be debuggable: [Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

Start a debug from Eclipse, choosing your device.

check the output in the `LogCat` View in Eclipse. There you will see the Exception Stack Trace.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you directly run the apk file on your device instead running on the emulator.??

Answer (score 0):

Check this in manifest file that you have set

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: Your answer has no relation to the question at all.

Comment: Well i too had same problem and i solved it by this, but if you think so this is wrong then Okay.

Comment: He talks about using SDK 10 on AVD and then using a Galaxy S4 which is probally running a SDK > 10, so why should his SDK version in the Manifest be a problem? Further more the question does not contain any clue to whats going on or what error has occured at all